# load only container section on submit in zend 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can anyone guide me to load only container section of page during page submit. All header, footer and sidebar will remain same.

I known, it is possible by using the ajax but I avoid the ajax. Please tell me if you know any other approach.

Thanks

Comment: And reason to avoid ajax is ?

Comment: no reason. i just want to know that it is possible without use of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Without Ajax, this is a bit complicated to load code from the server without reloading the entire page. :) 

If the code does not come from the server, I can propose 2 solutons:

1 - If the code is static, you put it in a hidden div and when submit, you show it, this is what I do to ask wait.

2 - If the code is dynamic (without specific informations from the server, you can use for example, informations form), you generate code in javascript and you show it in a div.